# Using constraint kinds and type families with 'limited' constraints

Tags: haskell, type-families, constraint-kinds

I'm working on an applicative functor that contains a monoid to "view" the execution. However, sometimes I don't care about this part at all, so the choice of monoid is irrelevant as it will never be consumed. I've simplified what I have into:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Exts

class Render a b where render :: a -> b
instance Render a () where render = const ()

class Merge a where
  type Renderer a b :: Constraint
  merge :: Renderer a b => a -> b

data Foo = Foo Bool

instance Merge Foo where
  type (Renderer Foo) m = (Render Bool m)
  merge (Foo b) = render b
```

`Render` is used to transform various `a`s into a single `b`. `Merge` is a big simplification of my actual functor, but the point is it contains a type family/constraint and my intention of that is to specify exactly what `Render`ers a `Merge` requires.

Now, I might want to "run" the `Merge`, but discard the view, which is akin to something like:

```
runFoo :: Merge a => a -> Int
runFoo x = case merge x of () -> 5
```

But this will fail because:

> Could not deduce `(Renderer a ())` arising from a use of `merge`

I chose `()` as my monoid because forall `a`, we have an instance of `Render a ()`. So if there was a way to say that `Merge a` just means a collection `Render` constraints then this would work fine. Of course, `Merge a` is more general than that - it could add arbitrary constraints, which explains the compilation error.

Is there anyway to achieve what I want *without* changing the signature of `runFoo`?

Comment: Does `Renderer` always include exactly one `Render`?

Comment: @Tinctorius - no, generally depends on the amount of distinct types in the fields of `Foo`

Comment: Is there a reason why `Merge` doesn't have `b` as a parameter as well?

Comment: @C.A.McCann - no reason why it doesn't, but I don't see much reason why it should either. If that would help things I could bring it in, but I can't immediately see how it would help.

Comment: Having something as a class parameter in general gives you more options for expressing tricky constraints. Didn't have anything specific in mind, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not scale if you have a lot of these cases, but this works:

```
class Renderer a () => Merge a where
  ...
```

Comment: I hadn't considered that. I could read that constraint as '`Merge`s should at least support rendering with the `()` monoid'. However, this does incur `UndecidableInstances`.

Comment: "UndecidableInstances is not a dangerous flag. It will never cause the type-checker to accept a program that `goes wrong.' The only bad consequence of using the flag is type checker's might be telling us that it cannot decide if our program is well-typed, given the context-stack--depth limit." http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/TypeClass.html#undecidable-inst-defense

Comment: I know that, I already use it in 3 other places ;) But ideally I like to find solutions that don't require it, even if for purely academic reasons. I'll probably accept this answer, just leaving the ground open for a bit longer though. This is indeed working a treat!